# Receive information from events and register in a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I try to listen to two events I have in smart contracts (one of them smart contract factory) that are related to each other and save the information I get in the dataBase.
But once I have several users using a smart contract at the same time then the events are activated the information coming to the wrong dataBase gets confused among the users

```js
const db = require("../connectDB/DB");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const EzeyNFTABI = require("../../client/src/Artifacts/EzeyNFT.json");
const EzeyNFTFactoryABI = require("../../client/src/Artifacts/EzeyNFTFactory.json");

const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(
  "wss://morning-twilight-cherry.matic-testnet.quiknode.pro/6ba9d2c5b8a046814b28f974c3643c679914f7ff/"
);

HDWalletProvider.prototype.on = wsProvider.on.bind(wsProvider);

let provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  "PRIVAE-KEY",
  wsProvider
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

let name;
let symbol;
let collectionAddress;
let addressWallet;
let walletID;
let tokenURI;
let description;

async function eventFactory_Handler(err, data) {
  let result = data.returnValues;
  if (!err) {
    name = result.name;
    symbol = result.symbol;
    collectionAddress = result.collectionAddress;
    addressWallet = result.addressWallet;
    walletID = result.walletID;
    console.log(result);
    EventFromMintNFT(collectionAddress);
  }
}
async function eventFromMintNFT_Handler(err, data) {
  let result = data.returnValues;
  try {
    if (!err) {
      tokenURI = result.tokenURI;
      description = result.description;
      console.log(result);
      await insertToCollectionTable();
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function eventFromMintNFT(newCollectionAddress) {
  try {
    let eventEmiterContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      EzeyNFTABI.abi,
      newCollectionAddress
    );
    await eventEmiterContract.events.newCollection(eventFromMintNFT_Handler);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
async function eventFromFactory() {
  try {
    let eventEmiterContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      EzeyNFTFactoryABI.abi,
      "0x0a77174a8F78E64fFE589288D2C47AE83189dEAd"
    );
    await eventEmiterContract.events.newCollection(eventFactory_Handler);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
} 

async function insertToCollectionTable(req, res) {
  try {
    async function insertToTable() {
      db.query(
        `INSERT INTO ezeyNFT.collectionNFT (NFTSymbol,NFTUrl,IDAddressWallet) VALUES ('${symbol}','${tokenURI}','${walletID}')  `,
        (err, newResult) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(newResult);
          return newResult;
        }
      );
    }

    db.query(
      `SELECT * FROM ezeyNFT.userNFT WHERE addressWallet = '${addressWallet}'  `,
      async (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else if (result.length == 0) {
          async function newUser() {
            db.query(
              `INSERT INTO ezeyNFT.userNFT (id,addressWallet) VALUES ('${walletID}','${addressWallet}')  `,
              (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                return res;
              }
            );
          }
          await newUser();

          await insertToTable();
        } else {
          await insertToTable();
        }
        // console.log(result);
        // res.send(result);
        return result;
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}  
}

eventFromFactory();


module.exports = {
  insertToCollectionTable, 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to get the events

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("infuralink"));
const ABI=[];
const Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI,"contractaddress");


web3.eth.getBlockNumber((error, result) => {
      if (!error) {
        Contract.getPastEvents(
          "eventname",{fromBlock:  result - 1000 ,toBlock: result},
          (error, events) => {
            if (!error) {
                var transactions = events;
                const value = transactions.reverse();
                console.log(value);
            }
            else
            {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
      }
      else
      {
      }
    });
```

This gives the events in a gap of 1000 blocks, trigger a cron to check for every 5 minutes or so,